How to get the app that launched a terminal instance?
I want to write a script for my team that will set up some value based on the (JetBrains) IDE they use (I need the path to the IDE application).
One way is to hardcode all the different IDEs and their potential paths, but I was wondering if I could retrieve it dynamically. If they all launch the script from the IDE integrated terminal, is there any command I could run in the terminal that would be able to retrieve the app that triggered the terminal instance?
Just in case it makes thing easier, we are all using macOS.

You could get the PPID from the shell in the Terminal instance, whose parent is would reflect the calling process, unless you launch using a launchd methodology. Then it would just point to launchd whose parent is process 1.   So what did you try??

"So what did you try??" -> what I was missing was $PPID exactly, as well as ps command. Knowing these two then it's just a matter of manipulating their outputs

Disclaimer: all the commands below are based on macOS. It's very likely they need to be tweaked for a different OS.
Script
TERMINAL_PPID=$(ps -eo pid,ppid | sed -nE  "s/${PPID}[[:space:]]+(\d*)/\1/p")
ps -eo pid,command | sed -nE  "s/${TERMINAL_PPID}[[:space:]]+(.*\.app).*/\1/p"

Explanations
$PPID give the PID (process ID) of the parent process.
Then we have to map that PID into an application path.
ps -eo pid,command will give the list of all the processes with their PID and corresponding command path separated by one or more spaces.
Running ps -eo pid,command | grep $PPID from the integrated terminal will give two results. One is the IDE command path, the other one is that very current grep command we are running.
We then need to extract the command path. Since grep doesn't support capturing groups, we can use sed for this:
ps -eo pid,command | sed -nE  "s/${PPID}[[:space:]]+(.*)/\1/p"

This will not match the current command (as it doesn't have a space after the pid) and will return the full command path of the IDE, something like /Applications/CLion.app/Contents/MacOS/clion.
In my case, I need the path to the .app folder, so I need to strip everything after:
ps -eo pid,command | sed -nE  "s/${PPID}[[:space:]]+(.*\.app).*/\1/p"

Ok so if I run the command above in the IDE's integrated terminal, this will give me the path to the IDE: /Applications/CLion.app.
Now there is one last thing to tackle, which is that if I write a script that is launched from the integrated terminal, $PPID will give the process id of the terminal.
I could ask my team to pass $PPID as an argument to the script. Better yet, I can retrieve the PPID of the PPID using ps and sed again:
ps -eo pid,ppid | sed -nE  "s/${PPID}[[:space:]]+(\d*)/\1/p

ps -eo pid,ppid will list of the PIDs and their corresponding PPID. This way I can look for the line with pid of the terminal ($PPID in the script) and get its PPID, which is the one of the IDE.
